# App to shrink Windows partition on WinXP

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-xp

I have a WinXP machine that I'd like to make dual-boot with Lubuntu.  The standard advice is to shrink the Windows partition from within Windows as Windows is fussy.

The problems I'm running into are this:

- Unlike Win7, WinXP doesn't have an internal utility for shrinking the Win partition.
- The main third-party program that I see recommended -- EaseUS -- is riddled with malware/spyware.
- GParted is a good program, but it doesn't meet the criteria of being a Windows program used to shrink Windows from within Windows.

So, what partitioning program should I be using within Windows?

UPDATE:   Success.   I tried a couple of third-party Wndows partition programs and one didn't work, the other did.  It was called AOMEI Partition Assistant

Thanks for the pep talk on GParted.  I was prepared to use it if the Windows proggies failed.  Apparently the success rate is better if a couple of disk-error checks are run first.  And one is supposed to uncheck "Round to Cylinders."

As for the install, was pleasantly surprised to find that at 512MB RAM I could still use the graphical Lubuntu installer.  I had read that the actual requirements were more than 512 MB.

Comment: You don't have to do it from within windows, you can do the partitioning from the live Lubuntu just before its installation.

Comment: During the installation of Ubuntu you get a slider, so you can choose how large the Ubuntu partition should be. I refer to the grafic installer of (L/X)ubuntu, not the text installer of the lubuntu alternativ DVD for PCs with 512 mb ram. And always remember: make backups before partitioning

Comment: Unfortunately, the computer in question has only 512MB RAM so the text installer will have to be used.  That will make it harder, but not impossible for me as a n00B.  But everyone has warned me against shrinking Windows during the install as opposed to doing it in Windows.  From what I'm hearing here, there doesn't seem to be any worries?

Comment: I've never experienced any issues when shrinking Winows partitions from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Do this from boot; go to [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) load your bootable utility [partedmagic](https://partedmagic.com/)
on a USB key, launch it at the boot stage - check you PC it is often F2 or F12 to get to boot menu; change the order to boot from USB.

**Warning - repartitioning can wreck your system! Read the instructions carefully!**

Good luck

Comment: This also uses Gparted or other linux utilities, which the OP wants to avoid. Note that Parted Magic isn't free, it costs at least $9.

Comment: I'd be willing to use Gparted (since it's free), if everyone agreed that it would work okay.  But I've read so many times that Windows is finicky about having it's partition shrunk outside of Windows itself.  So I'm kind of afraid to do it unless my fears are dispelled.  This will be only my second partitioning.  I did an earlier one on a more modern Windows system that had both a built-in Win-resizing utility and enough RAM to use a graphical Linux install.